# How do I fix my infinite loop from an if statement?

Tags: python, if-statement

> Alice has a W-word essay due tomorrow (1 ≤ W ≤ 10,000), but she's too
>   busy programming to bother with that! However, Alice happens to know
>   that H.S. High School's English teacher is sick of reading and grading
>   long essays, so she figures that if she just submits a "reasonable"
>   essay which fulfills the requirements but is as short as possible, she
>   may get some pity marks!
>
> As such, Alice wants to write a program to generate a sequence of W
>   words to pass off as her essay, where each word is any string
>   consisting of 1 or more lowercase letters ("a".."z") (not necessarily
>   a real English word). The essay will have no punctuation or
>   formatting, as those seem unnecessary to Alice. In an attempt to
>   disguise the essay's generated nature, Alice will insist that all W
>   words are distinct. Finally, for her plan to come together, she'll
>   make the sum of the W words' lengths as small as possible.
>
> Help Alice generate any essay which meets the above requirements.

As of now, I think I've identified a piece of code that is causing an infinite loop. However, I cannot find out how to fix it. My theory: the first if statement is contradicting with the other if statements, causing an infinite loop. It is starting to loop infinitely when it reaches third character words.

```
import string, math
w = int (raw_input(" "))
words = []
paragraph = ""
alphabet = string.ascii_lowercase

first_alpha = -1
second_alpha = 0
third_alpha = 1
switch_to_two_char = False
switch_to_three_char = False

def unique(s):
    return len(set(s)) == len(s)

x = 0 
while (x != w):
    word = ""
    if (x != 0):
        word = " "

    if (first_alpha >= 25):
        first_alpha = 0
        switch_to_two_char = True
    elif (second_alpha >= 25):
        second_alpha = 0
        first_alpha += 1
    elif (second_alpha >= 25 & first_alpha >= 25):
        first_alpha = 0
        second_alpha = 0
        switch_to_three_char = True
    elif (third_alpha >= 25):
        second_alpha += 1
        third_alpha = 0

    else:
        if (switch_to_two_char and not switch_to_three_char):
            second_alpha += 1
        if (switch_to_three_char):
            third_alpha += 1
        else:
            first_alpha += 1


    if (switch_to_two_char):
        word += alphabet[second_alpha]
        word += alphabet[first_alpha]
    elif (switch_to_three_char):
        word += alphabet[third_alpha]
        word += alphabet[second_alpha]
        word += alphabet[first_alpha]
    else:
        word += alphabet[first_alpha]

    if (unique(word) == 0):
        continue

    if (word in words):
        continue
    else:
        paragraph += word
        words.append (word)
        x += 1

print paragraph
```

Comment: Does `x` ever change? This question is equivalent to "is `word` ever not in `words`?" Print `x` at the end of the while loop to check.

Comment: Yeah, I see that it's intended to change, but does it? Do you ever enter the else block? If so, is something wrong with `w`? Inspect `w` to make sure it compares with integers properly

Comment: Tip: When you create a [mcve] make sure the program still (a) runs, and (b) clearly demonstrates the problem. It *is* a good idea to try to remove excess code like you did--thank you for that--but you need to make sure the code still shows what you mean to show. You don't want to cut out important bits such as `x += 1` that completely change the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question to address our comments! The question's looking a lot better.

Comment: This is a great opportunity to develop your debugging skills. You have a theory on what's broken--perfect! Now test your theory. A great way to do that is by inserting debugging printouts at strategic locations. Print out the values of key variables and see where things go awry. For example, you might print out `word` each iteration to see the words being generated.

Comment: The only problem is, the error only starts occurring when w >= 677, as that's when the three character distinct words start. So, I would have to print through 677 numbers until I can get to it! I've tried before, but I'll try again through a different method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When second_alpha add to 25, first_alpha+1 and second_alpha return to 0. So, when the first_alpha add to 25 finally, the second_alpha return to 0 again. Next loop, you program will go into this if-statement.

```
elif (first_alpha >= 25):
    first_alpha = 0
    switch_to_two_char = True
```

And then, both of first_alpha and second_alpha return to 0 again.